# Laravel 5.5 : redirect route and pass variable to other route, controller then display on view

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I was doing logic on AuthController.

```
// AuthController
$userPoint = $this->getLoginPoint($getUserUpdate);
return redirect()->intended(route('page.top_page'));
```

I want to pass variable $userPoint to other controller (PageController)

```
Route::get('/top-page', 'PageController@topPage')->name('page.top_page');
```

Here is my PageController

```
// PageController
public function index()
{
 // I want to receive variable $userPoint here
 return view('toppage', compact('UserPoint'));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Session:

Use [Session](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/session)
can help you get get datas from other controller action.

If your `$userPoint` is string or integer, just put it in session.

If it is a model instance, you can store its `id`. And in other controller 
 use the `id` to find your `userPoint`.

```php
// AuthController
$userPoint = $this->getLoginPoint($getUserUpdate);
$request->session()->put('userPoint', $userPoint);
return redirect()->intended(route('page.top_page'));
```

```php
public function index(Request $request)
{
 $userPoint = $request->session()->get('userPoint');
 return view('toppage', compact('userPoint'));
}
```

At last, remember to clear the userPoint after you logout.

#### Redis:

Use redis just like session. However you need to install redis firstly.

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis;
...
$userPoint = $this->getLoginPoint($getUserUpdate);
Redis::set('userPoint', $userPoint);
return redirect()->intended(route('page.top_page'));
```

And get userPoint from another controller.

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis;
...
public function index()
{
$userPoint = Redis::get('userPoint');
...
```

At last, remember to clear the userPoint after you logout.